# Using markdown text in textview / dynamic text editing in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, markdown

I have no code for this yet, I'm just looking for a starting point. I've searched for hours through blogs and forums and here, and I haven't found anything quite like what I'm looking for. I'd like to enable textview to understand markdown. * for italics, ** for bold, *** for bold italics, etc etc. Basically, I'd like to be able to format on the fly, without necessarily having to hit a button. However, I'm not sure where to start for this question. It would seem I'd need something watching for these specific symbols, and, when it finds them, to reformat what's between them. Or maybe there's a simple way I'm not seeing. Regardless, if someone has an idea of what direction I should be looking, it would be much appreciated.

Here's some pseudocode, I suppose, if it helps understand the thought process any

```
if textview.textBeingTyped = "*" && WatcherStart == false {
WatcherStart = true
set marker}

else if textview.textBeingTyped = "*" && WatcherStart == true {
WatcherStart = false
textview.text from marker to cursor.position = text.italicized
}
```

I suppose there'd also have to be a check to make sure the space between marker and position was > 1, unless I made my own version of markdown where each Bold, Italic, and BI were a different symbol. Maybe * for italic, % for bold, @ for BI? Or instead of toggling a boolean, it simply *counts* the symbols and every second one runs the code. Dunno. I can see a few different ways to maybe do it, but I don't know how to really accomplish them. I'd appreciate any help anyone can give on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

Markdown parsing and handling is difficult. It has multiple standards and different editors are doing it in a different way. Unless you're doing it for experimental purposes, but for commercial or production project, I would suggest you to use [apple/swift-cmark](https://github.com/apple/swift-cmark), [mattt/CommonMarkAttributedString](https://github.com/mattt/CommonMarkAttributedString) or [Down](https://github.com/johnxnguyen/Down) to do all the heavy (and it's heavy) lifting of markdown parsing.

Some of the libs I listed provide you with HTML code having MD as an input, some return `NSAttributedString`. Then It's up to you how you render the UI.

Naive approach, which can lead to performance problems in some cases, will be to just to try to parse and redraw text view along with user editing.

Sorry, for "link answer".