# Remove markdown characters with Textkit?

Tags: swift, textkit

I'm trying to build a markdown editor in macOS and I found this package:
https://github.com/kyle-n/HighlightedTextEditor

However, the one thing I would like to extend is the possibility to have markdown characters removed.

E.g when typng `**bold**`, it should dynamically render the bold text but without the asterisks. I assume I need to use a `NSLayoutManager` but not sure how to proceed. I'm quite new to Swift development and I tried following along the Text kit guides on WWDC but it kinda flew over my head. Any pointers on how to start?

Just to clarify: it should work for user input, so it needs to work for TextField, not Text alone

I found another post [Hide Markdown Characters with NSLayoutManager in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57467951/hide-markdown-characters-with-nslayoutmanager-in-swift) but I can't wrap my head around how to implement the glyphRange functionality

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66815962/using-markdown-text-in-textview-dynamic-text-editing-in-swift ? Alternatively, if that is an option, SwiftUI has Markdown built in.

Comment: You can't use markdown together with TextField. I need to have the ui update as the user types. As far as I know, Markdown in SwiftUI is only for Text, not textfields..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate this is for a TextField.